# How to click a button in a selected region with selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click a button in a selected region (or html) with selenium web driver.
I have selected region in a string variable and from this string which is a html string I want to click a button.

Now the problem is that if I will do something like this:-

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath(".....")).click();
```

It will search the whole page and click the first matching element but I dont want this.

I want to click the element contained within my string variable.  How can I achieve this with selenium ?

Comment: How is this selected region defined? Is it outlined by a container div? Then get to that div and then use the findElement method of the WebElement class. This will make sure that the element is found inside the parent element. If you use xpath for this later query append with a "."

Comment: you can only get an element by uniquely identifying it.. if it is not possible in your case now. -you need to get a string one as such.

Comment: Can you post the html?

Answer (score 0):

To click a *button* (*Child Node*) in a selected region captured within a *Parent Node* you can use the following algorithm where you need to specify a **dot** which stands for **Current Node (context)** in the beginning of *XPath* as follows :

```
var parent_node = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//xpath_parent_node"));
parent_node.FindElement(By.XPath(".//xpath_child_node")).Click(); // <- Note the . in the begining of the xpath
```